# Get unique list of links that match query

Tags: c#, linq, anglesharp

I am using anglesharp to parse a webpage and to then discover links that might be the contact page.

Here is my code:

```
        var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();

        string address = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/";

        Url baseurl = new Url(address);

        var document = await BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(baseurl);

        var links = document.Links.Where(x => ((IHtmlAnchorElement)x).Host == baseurl.Host ).ToList();

        var contacts = links.Where(x => ((IHtmlAnchorElement)x).PathName.ToLower().Contains("contact")).Select(x => ((IHtmlAnchorElement)x).PathName).Distinct();
```

It works but I am getting duplicate PathName values in contacts.  I want to only ever take one value for each `PathName` but the select/distinct isn't working.

Do I have to create my own custom comparer or is there a way to alter my linq query?  I don't need any of the other data, just the host and pathname.

Comment: Distinct must be work, May be you forget case sensitivity, So add ToLower() end of expression: ((IHtmlAnchorElement)x).PathName.ToLower()

Comment: Yes you were right!  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Reza said, `ToLower()` is needed, and a simpler approach is to select the `pathName` first and then do the filtering:

```
var contacts = links.Select(x => ((IHtmlAnchorElement)x).PathName.ToLower())
                    .Where(pathName => pathName.Contains("contact"))
                    .Distinct();
```